# Sharing URLs that Contains Dynamically Generated Content (XHR) on Facebook using FB Social Plugins

Tags: php, facebook, xmlhttprequest, facebook-social-plugins

I have a web page (written in PHP) that renders some html on the browser. Lets say the url for this webpage is 
`http://mywebsite/mywebpage.php`

On this page, There are a few links. By clicking on these links, the user is able to bring more content on to the page on the fly (without the whole page refreshing) For this I use  client side HTTP requests (i.e. XHR)

I want to let users share/like this page (including the XHR rendered content also). 
For this I use the Facebook social plug-ins.

The problem is the url of this web page that is posted to facebook is always
`http://mywebsite/mywebpage.php`

This url does not know anything about content on the page that was rendered using client side HTTP requests (by user clicking links on the page). So when someone takes this link from FB back to my webpage, they will just come to `http://mywebsite/mywebpage.php` - and this will show only the initial content on the page (without the dynamic client-side content).

Is there a way around this? How do I include the dynamically generated content on the page when a user shares the page on Facebook?